# Changing position and Font .phtml file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

I have .phtml file which have order button on product page.
How can I change font and position "Ask product Question" button on this code?
I have already this code;

```html
<?php $_product = $this->getParentBlock()->getParentBlock()->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if (Mage::helper('askfordetails')->checkIfMailForAskForDetailsIsSet()): ?>
    <a class="button popup-ask-question" href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('askfordetails/askfordetails', array('product_id' => $_product->getId())) ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('askfordetails')->__('Ask Product Question') ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and I try this but nothing happen;

```html
.askfordetails {
font-size:16px;
}
```

Also no have any .css files for this button.

Answer (score 0):

The class of this link is actually `popup-ask-question` and not `askfordetails` which is an helper and have nothing to do with CSS...

You should try

```
.popup-ask-question {
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.button.popup-ask-question {font-size:16px;}
```

should do the trick.

If not try:

```
.button.popup-ask-question {font-size:16px !important;}
```

If even this doesn't work please let me know so we can look into this issue some more.

Comment: I m not sure may I am wrong edit page but I'll add this code bottom of popup code and it's not working.I have not .css files.
am I required create a .css file in skin directory?
this file is in template folder which is askfordetails.phtml

Comment: Well adding css in a template file isn't best practice but should work.

Just try to add a css file in your skin:

`skin/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/css/additional.css`
And add is to your local.xml (if you dont have one create one in your layout folder)

`<?xml version="1.0">
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><file>css/additional.css</file></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>`

Let me know if this works out for you.